# KnockoutJS After Render retrieve data from viewModel issue

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I have a very strange behavior in going on KnockoutJS 1.2.1 (Can't switch to 2 yet, or believe me I would).

Basically, I have an after render set up on a template. In the after render, I need to retrieve data from my viewModel. When I try to get data from it by viewModel.stuff() inside the render function, a strrrange behavior is occurring. It seems to be calling render multiple times or something.

Here is the code...

```
var viewModel = {
    stuff: ko.observableArray([{ id : 1, name : 'Thing'},
        { id: 2, name : 'Thingier' },
        { id : 3, name : 'Thingiest' }])

};

window.render = function(el){
    // This line does weird stuff!!
    // Observe the console with and without it
    // All I want to do is get my stuff...
    var stuff = viewModel.stuff(); 
    console.log(el);
};

var update = function(){
    console.log(viewModel);
    viewModel.stuff.push({ id : 4, name : 'Thingiestest' });       
};    

$(function(){
    ko.applyBindings(viewModel);

    $("#add").click(function(){
       update(); 
    });
});
```

Here is the fiddle...

http://jsfiddle.net/jcreamer898/wZ5bD/

Just try commenting out the **var stuff = viewModel.stuff()** in the render function and observe the difference in the console log when clicking the button.

Appreciate any help here as I know this one's a little weird!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bindings are executed inside of a computed observable, so when you call `viewModel.stuff()` in your afterRender function you are creating a dependency for each on the `stuff` observable.

When you add a new item, `afterRender` is getting called after rendering each of the items again.

Look at the date here: http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/wZ5bD/4/

I am not sure of the exact thing that you want to accomplish, but if you need to do it in `afterRender` and don't want a dependency, then you could perform your action in a setTimeout 0. http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/wZ5bD/5/